# Why is memoization giving the wrong output?

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, memoization

I am tryna solve a question using recursion+memoization.  It is just modified Fibonacci with an additional `start+3` step that can be done only `K` times.  This is the recursive code I came up with:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int helper(int start, int N, int K) {
    // cout<<start<<" "<<N<<" "<<K<<"\n";
    if(start>N) return 0;
    if(start==N) return 1;
    
    int ans=0;
    ans=helper(start+1, N, K) + helper(start+2, N, K);
    if(K>0) {
        K--;
        ans=ans+helper(start+3, N, K);
    }
    
    return ans;
}

int main() {
    int T;
    cin>>T;
    while(T--) {
        int N, K;
        cin>>N>>K;
        cout<<helper(0, N, K)<<"\n";
    
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Just memoizing it and taking modulo 10^9+7 (the problem requires me to do it), I have:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<long long int> dp;
const unsigned int M = 1000000007;

int helper(long long int start, long long int N, int K) {
    // cout<<start<<" "<<N<<" "<<K<<"\n";
    if(start>N) return 0;
    if(start==N) return 1;
    if(dp[start]!=0) {
        return dp[start];
    }
    
    int ans=0;
    ans=(helper(start+1, N, K)%M + helper(start+2, N, K)%M)%M;
    if(K>0) {
        K--;
        ans=(ans%M+helper(start+3, N, K)%M)%M;
    }
    
    return dp[start]=ans;
}

int main() {
    int T;
    cin>>T;
    while(T--) {
        long long int N;
        int K;
        cin>>N>>K;
        dp.clear();
        dp.resize(N+5, 0);
        cout<<helper(0, N, K)<<"\n";
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The code is exactly the same, but for memoization and modulo.  When I run it on the following input:

> 1 
> 7 1

I get `41` in the first case, while `44` in the second one.  Obviously, I debugged and I expected some memoization or modulo issues.  However, I noticed that some of the *evaluations* are no longer being computed, by which I concluded some issue with the recursive calls.  Please note the diff of the calls [here](https://www.diffchecker.com/1IVrse3P) and working code snippets [here](https://ideone.com/xcH0tq) and [here](https://ideone.com/mv3DRJ).

Could someone please point out what I am missing?

Comment: Note: I am fairly confident the issue is not with modulo based on the diff attached above and also because my input is small enough that modulo does not really make any difference.

Comment: What is the algorithm doing? It looks like some sort of modified Fibonacci?

Comment: Yes, that's right.  Modified Fibonacci with an additional `start+3` step that can be done only `K` times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're caching results in `db` based entirely on `start`, and ignoring `K` entirely.   But `helper(0, 7, 0)` and `helper(0,7,7)` need to cache entirely different numbers at each index, based on whatever `K` is remaining.  So you need the cache *index* to also be based on `K`.

I see three ways to optimize:

- Have a cache of caches. `db[start]` would be a `std::vector`, and you'd use index `K` in that vector to access your item. This results in using significantly more memory.
- Abandon `std::vector` and use a `std::unordered_map`, where your key is a pair of (`start`, `K`).  (Possibly `std::pair<int, int>`, but better to use a struct with better names.) This should use drastically less memory, with little lost in speed.
- Only cache values when `K==0`.  This doesn't increase your cache size, but you also lose a lot of the caching benefits when `K` is large.

Comment: Ah, great!  I had not realized that.  Thank you! :)